# xcode and ad-hoc-distribution: can i bring xcode to automatically make an .ipa?

Tags: xcode, build-automation, ad-hoc-distribution

can i make, that when compiling in the adhoc-profile, i made for xcode, pack it into a zip complaining to itunes or an ipa, give it an automatic name (optional ... appname_date_time.zip) and copy it to a network-path ?

so, what is really my problem: i think i understood, that in a past-build-phase i can run a shell-script. but i haven´t done many shell-scripting now. can i zip on osx with the shell and for this case in a simple way ?

and can i let the message "no provisioned iphone connected" be gone ?

why ?
i want, that some company-internal people can load my software without email-spamming on each new release.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, build and archive builds at least the .ipa automatically. the rest might be just a second click and a script. so if no one has a more elegant solution, this is enough

Answer (score 0):

You can automate this, but need to get after the code signing, which is behind the last build phase you can add to Xcode. So the solution is creating a new aggregate target and define the shell script in there.

Here is an example of the whole process including a readme file on how to set it up: https://github.com/TheRealKerni/HockeyKit/tree/develop/client/iOS/Beta%20Automatisation

Answer (score 0):

Check out the BetaBuilder gem - https://github.com/lukeredpath/betabuilder.  It worked about 90% of the way for me - I had to re-route its guts a bit to make it work, but my fork (https://github.com/dts/betabuilder) works for me.  Hopefully, you can cobble together a solution for you (it was worth the effort for me!)